# Ejecutar pruebas que consultan una base de datos existente con Laravel 5.4 - Dusk

Tags: php, laravel, pruebas-unitarias

Necesito ejecutar pruebas automatizadas en el buscador con `Laravel 5.4` usando `Dusk`. La base de datos no se creó a partir del sistema de migraciones del framework por lo que tengo problemas para ejecutar las pruebas que hacen consultas a la base de datos.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such
>   file or directory (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`,
>   `password`, `remember_token`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
>   (Harrison Aufderhar Jr., mayer.morris@example.com,
>   $2y$10$6VIOEVoj.AJFOJlRrg7jGu9FckcJj/fWP3UazIPhtM9m07sTWrkFG,
>   drfrdsUS41, 2017-09-26 11:32:05, 2017-09-26 11:32:05))
>
> ```
> Caused by PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
> ```

Comment: Hola, me da la sensación de que el problema no tiene que ver con el tema de las migraciones. ¿Tenés bien configurada la base de datos? Si modificaste el archivo `.env` después de iniciar el servidor deberías reiniciarlo para que reconozca los cambios

Comment: Si, es culpa mía. En la configuración de ambiente del proyecto debo especificar  la ruta de mysql.

lo solucioné así.

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=base de datos
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_SOCKET = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: Ok. Recuerdo haber tenido este problema hace un par de años y por suerte ya no tengo que especificar el SOCKET. ¿Que version de php estas usando?

Comment: En estos momentos PHP Version 5.6.30